# IE 11 width percentage not working with table columns?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, width, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to build a dynamic table, with columns based on the number of Phases/Elements I have. These columns contains Tasks/Tickets, which are defined as divs
Here is a code snipet:

```
var prozent = 100/itemCounter;

            while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();

                table1Row += '<td style="width:' + prozent + '%" contenteditable="true" id="headline' + oListItem.get_id() + '">' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + '</td>';
                table2Row += '<td class="droppable" id="column' + oListItem.get_id() + '" style="border-right: solid 1px #0072C6;"></td>';

            }
            tableComplete = '<tr class="headline">' + table1Row + '</tr><tr class="tableheight">' + table2Row + '</tr>';

            jQuery('#tableId').html(tableComplete.toString());
```

For example: When I have 5 Elements each row should be 20% width.
With Google Chrome and Firefox everything is displayed properly, when the columns contain tasks/tickets. With IE 11 the columns containing tasks/tickets are much larger in width than the other empty columns.

Why is IE 11 displaying this so wrong and does someone know how to fix this?